# Proper sizing of svg filter

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I'm using a very simple Gaussian blur in svg:

```
<filter id="filter2" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="120%" height="120%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5"/>
</filter>
```

This effect is basically 15px wide at each side (after that the blur is too weak).
How to I properly encode that in the filter size (x, y, width, height) such that I can reuse the filter for arbitrary elements?
In particular I have some small circles (around 10px wide) and some bigger polygons (a few hundred px wide).
`x` and `y` are easy enough, I can just set them to `-15`.
However, `width` and `height` are a problem. `120%` is not enough for the small elements and way too much for the bigger ones. I'm converting the svg to a pdf and this causes huge margins.

Ideally I want to set something like `100% + 15px`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hybrid dimensions directly in your filter size declaration (yet - it might be possible with SVG2 - not sure). Today, you must choose either % or absolute units (objectBoundingBox or userSpaceOnUse), so you need to define multiple filters with different dimensions if you want a fixed size overflow on different size shapes. At least it's not too much extra document weight.

One alternative is to just use the default filter margins (+/- 10% all around) and change to a % sizing for the std Deviation like so:

```
<filter id="filter2" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3%"/>
</filter>
```

It will create variable size blurs in absolute terms - but you'll only need one filter declaraion.